Add Dashed line to legend for each sites Average
I have a ggplot that plots 3 data points for each of the 5 sites. I have the lines and points color coded based on site. I then plot the average of each site and have the color match but make the line dashed. I would like to add a dashed line to the legend for each site with corresponding color under each solid line on the legend.
Data
chl_no_est <- structure(list(sample_date = structure(c(1683763200, 1683763200, 
1683676800, 1683676800, 1683676800, 1689206400, 1689206400, 1689120000, 
1689120000, 1689120000, 1694649600, 1694649600, 1694563200, 1694649600, 
1694563200), tzone = "America/Los_Angeles", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), event = c("May 2023", "May 2023", "May 2023", "May 2023", 
"May 2023", "July 2023", "July 2023", "July 2023", "July 2023", 
"July 2023", "September 2023", "September 2023", "September 2023", 
"September 2023", "September 2023"), station_name = c("TMDL-R1", 
"TMDL-R2", "TMDL-CL", "TMDL-R3", "TMDL-R4", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", 
"TMDL-CL", "TMDL-R3", "TMDL-R4", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", "TMDL-CL", 
"TMDL-R3", "TMDL-R4"), var = c("Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", 
"Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", 
"Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", 
"Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", 
"Chlorophyll a"), result = c(8.86, 41.3, 8.01, 10.5, 112, 53.2, 
81.7, 61.9, 74.5, 103, 108, 53.3, 10.6, 27.8, 24.4), mean_var = c(56.6866666666667, 
58.7666666666667, 26.8366666666667, 37.6, 79.8, 56.6866666666667, 
58.7666666666667, 26.8366666666667, 37.6, 79.8, 56.6866666666667, 
58.7666666666667, 26.8366666666667, 37.6, 79.8)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), groups = structure(list(
    station_name = c("TMDL-CL", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", "TMDL-R3", 
    "TMDL-R4"), .rows = structure(list(c(3L, 8L, 13L), c(1L, 
    6L, 11L), c(2L, 7L, 12L), c(4L, 9L, 14L), c(5L, 10L, 15L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))



dry_season_1year_events <- data.frame(event = c("May 2023", "June 2023", "July 2023", "August 2023", "September 2023"))



Code
annotation_mean_chl <- chl_no_est %>% 
  select(event, station_name, result) %>% 
  group_by(station_name) %>% 
  mutate(avg_result = mean(result))
  


chl_no_est$event <- factor(chl_no_est$event, levels = dry_season_1year_events$event)


annotation_chl <- data.frame(
   x = c("May 2023"),
   y = c(158),
   label = c("Target Seasonal Average: 150 mg/m2")
)



ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = chl_no_est, aes(x = event, y = result, color = station_name, group = station_name), size = 0.8) +
  geom_point(data = chl_no_est, aes(x = event, y = result, color = station_name, group = station_name)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(150), linetype = "solid", color = "black", size = 0.7) +
  geom_line(data = annotation_mean_chl, aes(x=event, y=avg_result, color = station_name, group = station_name), linetype=2) +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE, name = NULL) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",  # Place legend under the x-axis
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size=.01, color="grey60" )) +
  labs(y="Chlorophyll a (mg/m2)") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 200), breaks = seq(0, 200, by = 20),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_text(data = annotation_chl, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label), nudge_x = 0.1)


None, unsure how to proceed.

One quick and easy option would be to use the ggnewscale package to add a second color scale for your dashed mean lines.
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = chl_no_est, aes(x = event, y = result, color = station_name, group = station_name), size = 0.8) +
  geom_point(data = chl_no_est, aes(x = event, y = result, color = station_name, group = station_name)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(150), linetype = "solid", color = "black", linewidth = 0.7) +
  geom_text(data = annotation_chl, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), nudge_x = 0.1) +
  scale_color_viridis(
    discrete = TRUE, name = NULL,
    guide = guide_legend(order = 1)
  ) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(data = annotation_mean_chl, aes(
    x = event, y = avg_result,
    color = station_name,
    group = station_name,
  ), linetype = 2) +
  scale_color_viridis(
    discrete = TRUE, name = NULL,
    guide = guide_legend(order = 2)
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = .01, color = "grey60"),
    legend.margin = margin()
  ) +
  labs(y = "Chlorophyll a (mg/m2)") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 200), breaks = seq(0, 200, by = 20),
    expand = c(0, 0)
  )


And a more elaborated approach would be to use a custom key glyph function which combines two segmentsGrob and a pointsGrob to get rid of the duplicated label. (The code below is simply a stripped   down version of draw_key_path and draw_key_point.) Additionally this requires to set show.legend=FALSE for the geom_point and the second geom_line:
draw_key_cust <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (is.null(data$linetype)) {
    data$linetype <- 0
  } else {
    data$linetype[is.na(data$linetype)] <- 0
  }
  grob1 <- grid::segmentsGrob(
    0.1, 0.75, 0.9, 0.75,
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = data$colour,
      lwd = .8 * .pt,
      lty = 1
    )
  )

  grob2 <- grid::segmentsGrob(
    0.1, 0.25, 0.9, 0.25,
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = data$colour,
      lwd = .7 * .pt,
      lty = 2
    )
  )

  data$shape <- 19
  stroke_size <- data$stroke %||% 0.5
  stroke_size[is.na(stroke_size)] <- 0
  grob3 <- grid::pointsGrob(0.5, 0.75,
    pch = data$shape,
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = data$colour,
      fontsize = 1.5 * .pt + stroke_size * .stroke / 2,
      lwd = stroke_size * .stroke / 2
    )
  )

  grid::gList(
    grob1,
    grob2,
    grob3
  )
}

ggplot(chl_no_est, aes(x = event, y = result, color = station_name, group = station_name)) +
  geom_line(
    linewidth = 0.8,
    key_glyph = "cust"
  ) +
  geom_point(
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(150), linetype = "solid", color = "black", linewidth = 0.7) +
  geom_text(
    data = annotation_chl, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), nudge_x = 0.1,
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_color_viridis(
    discrete = TRUE, name = NULL,
    guide = guide_legend(order = 1)
  ) +
  geom_line(data = annotation_mean_chl, aes(
    y = avg_result
  ), linetype = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = .01, color = "grey60"),
    legend.margin = margin()
  ) +
  labs(y = "Chlorophyll a (mg/m2)") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 200), breaks = seq(0, 200, by = 20),
    expand = c(0, 0)
  )



In you first solution, how I would adjust the text size of the legend labels for the dashed lines? It seems I would do that with in the scale_color_viridis(guide=guide_legend(theme())) of the order = 2? Yet when I try that it places null values in the legend.

Try with guide_legend(...., theme = theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 4))).
